# flutter form with nested/reactive model / reactive_forms

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Going through different tutorials and sources, i'm trying to get a dynamic form in a flutter app, but i'm having a bad time with my use case that looks like advanced.

**What i got working:**
create a reactiveform with only fixed strings and an int.
My form for reference:

```dart
final form = fb.group({
    'name': ['',  Validators.required,],
    'category': ['',  Validators.required,],
    'instructions': ['',],
    'unit':  [0,  Validators.required,],
});
```

and:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
ReactiveForm(
  formGroup: this.form,
  child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    ReactiveTextField(
      formControlName: 'name',
      validationMessages: (control) => {
        ValidationMessage.required:
          'The name must not be empty',
      },
      ...
    ),
  ],
),
```

**What i'm trying to achieve with no success:**
embed another object.The goal is to allow the user to add steps as much as needed, dynamically. So i went the Array< Step > way, but i could not figure how to get it working even with a simple string list...
It's supposed to work with:

```dart
final form = fb.group({
  ...
  'steps': fb.array([
    'step 1',
    'step 2',
  ]),
});
```

And then add a new step to the form with:

```dart
void _addStep(){
  final array = form.control('steps') as FormArray<String>;
  array.add(
  FormControl<String>(value: 'next step'),
  );
}
```

The thing is, I have no idea how to create widgets for this, and i can't find examples with arrays.

I guess i'm supposed to add a ReactiveFormArray() to my build function, but I have no idea how to build something that's supposed to be a single widget with a dynamic list of ReactiveTextField (or just TextFormField, anyway):

```dart
ReactiveFormArray(
  formArrayName: 'steps',
  builder: (BuildContext context, FormArray<dynamic> array, Widget child) {
      **??**
  },
),
```

I tried a lot of things and got my best results using reactive_forms, following https://pub.dev/packages/reactive_forms, but i'm open if you have a better solution.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: you can use code block for code section

Answer (score 1):

Use FormGroup instead of fb.group and convert [] into FormControl.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reactive_forms/reactive_forms.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Example());
}

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  final steps = [
    'step1',
    'step2',
  ];

  final form = FormGroup({
    // 'name': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required,]),
    // 'category': FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required,]),
    // 'instructions': FormControl<String>(),
    // 'unit': FormControl<int>(validators: [Validators.required,]),
    'steps': FormArray<String>([]),
  });

  FormArray<String> get selectedSteps => form.control('steps') as FormArray;

  @override
  void initState() {
    selectedSteps.addAll(
      steps.map((step) => FormControl<String>(value: '')).toList(),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget _buildStepListItem(step) {
    return ReactiveTextField(
      formControlName: this.steps.indexOf(step).toString(),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: step,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Steps',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ReactiveForm(
          formGroup: this.form,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ReactiveFormArray<String>(
                formArrayName: 'steps',
                builder: (context, formArray, child) => Column(
                  children: this.steps.map(_buildStepListItem).toList(),
                ),
              ),
              ReactiveFormConsumer(
                builder: (context, form, child) {
                  return RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Send'),
                    onPressed: form.valid
                        ? () {
                      print(this.selectedSteps.rawValue);
                    }
                        : null,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```